# openai.createChatCompletion() is not return event when I turn stream to true in aws lambda function

Tags: node.js, events, aws-lambda, streaming, openai-api

I have created a function in `python` that returns steaming data from `openai`. the code snippet bellow works perfectly good.

```
def get_data():
            trained_model = train_model(relevent_data, question)

            response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
                messages=trained_model,
                model=GENERATIVE_MODEL,
                max_tokens=OPENAI_MAX_TOKEN,
                temperature=OPENAI_TEMPERATURE,
                stream=True,
            )

            complete_answer = ""
            for event in response:
                event_text = event["choices"][0]["delta"]
                answer = event_text.get("content", "")  # RETRIEVE CONTENT
                complete_answer += answer
                yield answer

        return Response(get_data(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

Since Lambda is not supporting streaming using `Python` and instead supports `node.js`.I switched to `node.js`. However I facing an issue which the `openai.createChatCompletion` response is not an event as expectec. here is the response I recieved.

```
const trained_model = await train_model(relevent_data, question);

const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
  messages: trained_model,
  model: GENERATIVE_MODEL,
  max_tokens: OPENAI_MAX_TOKEN,
  temperature: OPENAI_TEMPERATURE,
  stream: true,
});
```

The response I recieved:

```
 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomain      Authorization: 

'Bearer my-openai-key data:    `{"messages":[{"role":"system","content":"My trained model"             Context:"my content"    Answer:"}],"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo","max_tokens":1000,"temperature        'Authorization: Bearer my-openai-key  data: 'data:    {"id":"chatcmpl-7JFj3EkpA02LMyxmiQr7","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1684823037,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"role":"assistant"},"index":0,"finish_    'data:    {"id":"chatcmpl-7JFj3EkpA02LMyxmiQrM6njD4mxh7","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1684823037,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"content":"Hello"},"index":0,"finish_reaso    'data:    {"id":"chatcmpl-7JFj3EkpA02LMyxmiQrM6njD4mxh7","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1684823037,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"content":"!"},"index":0,"finish_reason":n    'data:    {"id":"chatcmpl-7JFj3EkpA02LMyxmiQrM6njD4mxh7","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1684823037,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"content":"    I"},"index":0,"finish_reason":    'data:    {"id":"chatcmpl-7JFj3EkpA02LMyxmiQrM6njD4mxh7","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1684823037,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"content":"    am"},"index":0,"finish_reason"    'data: {"id":"chatcmpl- 'data:    {"id":"chatcmpl-7JFj3EkpA02LMyxmiQrM6njD4mxh7","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1684823037,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0301","choices":[{"delta":{"content":"    The"},"index":0,"finish_reason    'data:    {"id":"chatcmpl-7JFj3EkpA02LMyxmiQrM6njD4mxh7","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1684823037,"mode'...    1568 more char}
```

as you can see from the above snippet, response is an object and if I use
`response.on("data", (chunk) => { console.log("====Cunk=====: ", chunk.toString()); });`

it will gives me an error the type of response is not an [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#event_stream_format) it's object
however the `response.data` contains a `delta` field.
I consoled the type of `resonse.data` which is `String` and then I tried `JSON.parse(response.data)` again it throws an error.

I am quite confused, and I am not sure if I am missing something , I have refrenced to  the official documentian of [openai createChatCompletion](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create#chat/create-stream)

Could you pleas help me why this issue is occurring? Thank you in advance for your assistance.

**Edit and quick solution:**

I come across a discussion [here](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/issues/18) and I find out there is an npm package called `openai-ext` [here](https://github.com/justinmahar/openai-ext/) which is currently functional.

here is my update code:

```
const trained_model = await train_model(relevent_data, question);
const streamConfig = {
  openai: openai,
  handler: {
    onContent(content, isFinal, stream) {
      console.log("====content===: ", content);

    },
    onDone(stream) {
       console.log("Done!");
    },
    onError(error, stream) {
      console.error(error);
    },
  },
};

await OpenAIExt.streamServerChatCompletion(
  {
    model: GENERATIVE_MODEL,
    messages: trained_model,
    max_tokens: OPENAI_MAX_TOKEN,
    temperature: OPENAI_TEMPERATURE,
  },
  streamConfig
);
```